# Blazor client side UI updates are not reflected

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly App hosted in Ubuntu with Nginx as a proxy. However, when I publish the application and upload it to the server, any UI changes I have made are not reflected on the client. The application is a PWA.

service-worker.js

```
// In development, always fetch from the network and do not enable offline support.
// This is because caching would make development more difficult (changes would not
// be reflected on the first load after each change).
self.addEventListener('fetch', () => { });
```

service-worker.published.js

```
// Caution! Be sure you understand the caveats before publishing an application with
// offline support. See https://aka.ms/blazor-offline-considerations

self.importScripts('./service-worker-assets.js');
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(onInstall(event)));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(onActivate(event)));
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(onFetch(event)));

const cacheNamePrefix = 'offline-cache-';
const cacheName = `${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version}`;
const offlineAssetsInclude = [ /\.dll$/, /\.pdb$/, /\.wasm/, /\.html/, /\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.css$/, /\.woff$/, /\.png$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.gif$/, /\.ico$/ ];
const offlineAssetsExclude = [ /^service-worker\.js$/ ];

async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, { integrity: asset.hash }));
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}

async function onActivate(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Activate');

    // Delete unused caches
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys();
    await Promise.all(cacheKeys
        .filter(key => key.startsWith(cacheNamePrefix) && key !== cacheName)
        .map(key => caches.delete(key)));
}

async function onFetch(event) {
    let cachedResponse = null;
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
        // For all navigation requests, try to serve index.html from cache
        // If you need some URLs to be server-rendered, edit the following check to exclude those URLs
        const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate';

        const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
    }

    return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
}

/* updated 2020-12-22 11:19 */
```

I have tried the following to get the changes to be updated in the browser:

1. Deleted all the published files on the server, uploaded new files, and restarted the server
2. Restarted the website service
3. Added a timestamp to service-worker.published.js every time I upload a new version of the site.
4. Deleted the application cache using the clear storage feature and made sure to select all checkboxes.

[image: clear data]

Not sure how to get the site to refresh my changes after publishing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: After you update and re-publish, try the following: close your browser and re-open it. Open dev tools and select the network tab. Navigate to the site (this should then download your new service worker) - check there is a transfer of the service worker. check the application tab/service worker section - it should show an update is available but not active. Select the option "update on reload" and reload the page - the service worker should change to activated and running. Check the content of the service worker - ensure it is updated. If any of this fails, check the network traffic for problem

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thanks for the response. I had attempted what you suggested, however nothing was working. I finally figured out what it was. It turns out I was only updated the service worker and base dlls that are generated by the publish functionality in visual studio. I also had to update the files located in the _framework folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much frustration, it turns out the files in the _framework folder that is also generated by the publish functionality in Visual Studio must also be updated. I hope this helps someone avoid a long and frustrating day.

Comment: When we run a new compilation those _framework files aren't updated? Everytime i complile i have to clear cache which is a pain in the ass and i'm going to have problems when publishing.

Comment: This was my experience while using Blazor. I stopped using the technology for the project I was working on and went with something else. I'm hoping in future releases things will be much more robust. Unless someone has updates on the issue is fixed.